# How to always show two decimal places on a number in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, number-formatting

Folks,

I have a existing stored procedure that I'm trying to update to always show two decimal places even when it's a whole number or single decimal number.

This stored procedure builds out a message that has to show `v_credit_amt` as a two decimal number, yet the value assigned to `v_credit_amt` can be either a whole number or single decimal or a two decimal value
i.e. 175 should display as 175.00, 250.5 should display as 250.50, 395.95 should display as 395.95.

Here is the relevant stock pl/sql

```
v_credit_amt        number(22,2);
select NVL(sit_credit_limit,0)
  into v_credit_amt
  from sites
 where sit_pkey = p_site_id;
```

I thought that formatting via to_char during the select would solve this, ala

```
select NVL(to_char(sit_credit_limit, 'fm99999.00'),0)
  into v_credit_amt
  from sites
 where sit_pkey = p_site_id;

--v_credit_amt := to_char(v_credit_amt, 'fm99999.00');
insert into SQL_TXT values (v_credit_amt);
commit;
```

As you can see from the commented out line above, I've also tried it once the v_credit_amt variable is defined

I've also tried it with the to_number function

```
select NVL(to_number(sit_credit_limit, '99999.00'),0)
  into v_credit_amt
  from sites
 where sit_pkey = p_site_id;
```

However if the value stored in the sit_credit_limit column is a whole number without decimals, or a number like 250.5 `v_credit_amt` shows the same in all cases when querying SQL_TXT table I'm inserting to for debugging.

```
SQL> select * from SQL_TXT;

COL1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
175
250.5
```

This particular event simply concatenates multiple message portions into a single long message string that is returned i.e.

```
if p_message_id = '14' then
   v_message := 'Comtrol Check In Message Posted';
   v_string  := v_string || '008' || lpad(length(v_fname || ' ' || v_lname), 3, '0') || v_fname || ' ' || v_lname;
   v_string  := v_string || '059' || lpad(1, 3, '0') || '0';
   --v_string  := v_string || '089' || lpad(1, 3, v_credit_amt) || to_char(v_credit_amt);
   v_string  := v_string || '089' || lpad(length(to_char(v_credit_amt, 'fm9999999.00')), 3, '0') || to_char(v_credit_amt, 'fm9999999.00');
   v_string  := v_string || '106' || lpad(length(nvl(v_acct_number,'')), 3, '0') || v_acct_number;
   --v_string  := v_string || '106' || v_acct_number;
   v_string  := v_string || '164' || lpad(1, 3, '0') || '0';
   v_string  := v_string || '174' || lpad(length(v_rm_phone_num), 3, '0') || v_rm_phone_num;
   v_string  := v_string || '175' || lpad(length(v_rm_id), 3, '0') || v_rm_id;
   v_string  := v_string || '183' || lpad(1, 3, '0') || '0';
endif;
```

However I cannot get the final string to properly have two decimals in all use cases.

For example if the value in the db is 125 I get this for a final string

`144450034629999008009Bob Smith05900100{89006125}1060073307542164001017400340917500
34091830010`

however it should have been

`144450034629999008009Bob Smith05900100{89007125.00}1060073307542164001017400340917500
34091830010`

Sorry for the formatting above, I can't see how to bold a section without a code block so I've highlighted the relative portions instead {}

What am I missing if I need to always display a number to two decimals even if a whole or 1 decimal value is given?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You actually, have to insert the data with formatting. (Assuming the targeted column is `VARCHAR`) What ever format you fetch and put into a `NUMBER` variable, will be a `NUMBER`.

A number doesn't have a format to be saved after-all. Only for display, the formatting comes into picture.

```
insert into SQL_TXT values (TO_CHAR(v_credit_amt,'FM99999.00'));
commit;
```

If the *INSERT-ed* column is `NUMBER` again.

You still want to go with

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(COL1,'FM99999.00') FROM SQL_TEXT;
```

Comment: Updated original question with more information.  I actually need to take the number from the database and save it to a variable as a string always including two decimals as what this proc returns is a concatenation of multiple strings into a single string.  There is no final insert into a database it's all formatting of data and returning it.

Comment: @Jchieppa [Please Check this fiddle URL](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7d/3033) . Your problem statement is not valid.

Comment: @Jchieppa the only possibility I guess is, you probably execute the version of code without `TO_CHAR()` , you commented out here.